# Как сделать публикацию ASP.Net Core на Apache в Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache2, развертывание, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Нашёл документацию по публикации Core приложения на Apache в Centos https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy . Подскажите как опубликовать Core приложение на Apache в Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил Nginx и развернул приложение на нём. Следовал вот инструкциям из этой статьи:
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.junian.net/2017/01/running-your-first-aspnet-core-web-app-on-ubuntu-16-04.html)